# What can we do when load balancer becomes the bottleneck?

Tags: load-balancing, system-design

I just started learning load balancers. Taking a server side application (http/https) load balancer as an example, I assume it listens a specific ip address, then forward the http requests to available servers based on its algorithm.

So is it possible for a load balancer to become a bottleneck? Because it's listening a specific ip address, all requests will first go to the single load balancer. So I think there could be a scenario where the amount of traffic is beyond the limit/capacity of the load balancer.

When it becomes a bottleneck, what can we do? Can we use multiple load balancers?

I think one possible solution is to use multiple load balancers and expose all the ips to clients. (This sounds like client side load balancing) So when a client wants to send a request, it can pick from the ip pool and then send a request to one of the load balancers. (For example, ZooKeeper could be used here.) Is this a working solution? Is there any other way to use multiple load balancers?

Thanks.
Ethan

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your last suggestion works with adding a little twist: The usual approach is to publish the load balancer IP addresses under the same domain name.

This is called [DNS load balancing](https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/dns-load-balancing/). Clients will ask for the IP resolution for your load balancer's domain name and they will get different IP addresses on a [round-robin fashion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS).

To configure DNS load balancing you have to add multiple A records for your load balancer's domain name to your DNS configuration. [Here](https://www.linux.com/learn/intro-to-linux/2018/3/simple-load-balancing-dns-linux) you can find an example guide for that.

Comment: Thanks Oresztesz, that's a great answer!